# what do we call the way women tie up their hair

Tags: phrases, expressions

Different word or phrases to describe the way the way women tie up their hair in a bundle on top of their head.

Comment: Like a bun? Braids?  Do you have a picture?

Comment: Here's one of many sites with a [non-exhaustive list of hairstyles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hairstyles) with pictures.

Comment: I do not agree with the fact that this question is a not real one, but your phrasing is terrible also for a not native, uncompetent of English language. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**coiffure** [- a person's hairstyle, typically an elaborate one](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=coiffure&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=FBp7UNe8IMKk0QXU8YAI&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3a3f773d9ccb5448&bpcl=35277026&biw=1217&bih=821) covers all styles.

**bun** [- a woman's hairstyle where the hair is brought together into a round shape at the back of the head](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bun_2) is OP's specific one.

You can speak of a [high top bun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zqc2twpSIYw) if you think the difference between back/top of the head is significant.

Or there's the [beehive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beehive_%28hairstyle%29) hairstyle, but I'll spare you Amy Winehouse - here's a less extreme one...

[image]